# Drupal 6 theme add / edit content form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms

Drupal 6 theme add / edit content form

In Drupal 6, we can add new content type "content-type".
We want to theme /node/add/content-type by template file.
We want to theme the edit form /node/$nid/edit of this content-type also by template file.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to understand the naming convention of tpl files in Drupal. This link will help https://www.drupal.org/node/1089642

According to documentation,

```
"http://www.example.com/node/1/edit" would result in the following suggestions:

page-node-edit.tpl.php
page-node-1.tpl.php
page-node.tpl.php
page.tpl.php
```

Either you can try adding content-type in the naming as suggested(I have not tried it personally), or if there are few customization to be done, adding a check like

```
<?php if($node->type == 'content_type_name') ?>
```

over available variables in "page-node-edit.tpl.php" will also do.